# Lumen API gateway uses it's database cofigurations

Tags: api, microservices, lumen, api-gateway

I am developing a microservices app with lumen, I have two services, Auth and Order. The Auth service is where I handle authentication logic, register, login, ...etc. In Order service I have the logic of submitting new order, get the order status, ..etc. And I have an API gateway which is the entry point to the app. The issue is that when I make a request from the API gateway to one of the services, it uses its (the API gateway) database configuration. That is, let's say the order service is using 'order' database and the API gateway is using the 'gateway' database, when making a request to order service, it uses the 'gateway' database to do database operations in the 'order' service and of course it throws an exception of table not found in 'gateway' database. So how can I solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found what the problem was, I will put what I have found here, maybe someone will need it.

The problem was simply caused because there is an issue with Apache on Windows, I moved to Nginix and the problem solved.